# set RadioButton value true once its focus and hit enter button in asp:RadioButton

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote following script to once click other checkbox to be uncheck, its working fine , but once I click tabkey its not getting check or uncheck , its only getting focus,

Script

```
function toggle(obj) {
    if (obj.value == "optMale") {
        document.getElementById('<%=optFemale.ClientID%>').checked = false;
    }
    else if (obj.value == "optFemale") {
        document.getElementById('<%=optMale.ClientID%>').checked = false;
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="col-sm-1 padding0">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optMale" Checked="true" runat="server" TabIndex="110" AutoPostBack="true" onClick="toggle(this)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 labelText2">Male</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 padding0">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optFemale" runat="server" TabIndex="111" AutoPostBack="true" onClick="toggle(this)" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 labelText2">Female</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like you're missing some javascript.  What events have you attached the toggle function to?

Comment: @DottedT onClick="toggle(this)"

Comment: "once I click tabkey its not getting check or uncheck"  That's the desired action.  Hitting the tab key should advance focus to the next element that can be focused on.  After that it's up to the user to decide the next action.

I.E. Clicking on a link or button to take them to the next page, action or set a radio button state.

What you're implying is that you want to override the standard user interaction by having the tabkey fire a nonstandard action by checking or unchecking a radio button.  This will confound any user and make their experience on the page frustrating. Don't do it.

Comment: Select a same name for both of radio buttons e.g name="gender"

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as follows. It could be done like what you said by jquery libraries.But like Dotted said, what you wanted to do is not reasonable. Maybe you can think of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(obj) {
        if (obj.value == "optMale") {
            document.getElementById('optFemale').checked = false;
          //  document.getElementById('<%=optFemale.ClientID%>').checked = false;
        }
        else if (obj.value == "optFemale") {
           document.getElementById('optMale').checked = false;
         //   document.getElementById('<%=optMale.ClientID%>').checked = false;
        }
    } 
     $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#optMale").focus(function() {
        document.getElementById('optFemale').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('optMale').checked = true;
    });
    $("#optFemale").focus(function() {
    document.getElementById('optFemale').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('optMale').checked = false;
    });
    });
</script>
LAYOUT-------
<asp:RadioButton ID="optMale" Checked="true" runat="server" TabIndex="110"  onClick="toggle(this)"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="optFemale" runat="server" TabIndex="111"  onClick="toggle(this)" />
```